# GDPR Contact Update across matching Contacts by Email

Tags: apex

I have 3 Contact records with the same email address.
I want to check off EmailOptOut on one, and have that synch with the other three based on Email address.

ContactToUpdate.size = 3, however the other two records are not updating.

```
private void ContactPrivacySynch()
//This method aligns and synchs the HasOptedOutOfEmail or DoNotCall values between all Contact records where the email match.
//Due to duplicate contacts, we want to ensure that their wish of not being marketed too is aligned between all records.
//Part of GDPR    
{
List<Contact> ContactUpdates = new List<Contact>();
List<Contact> ContactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
for( Contact newContact : (List<Contact>)Trigger.new){
    Contact oldContact = NULL;

    //If update, grab old record for comparison
    if(Trigger.IsUpdate) 
    { 
        oldContact = ((Map<Id, Contact>)Trigger.oldMap).get(newContact.ID);  
    }

    //Add to list only if NEW or HasOptedOutOfEmail or DoNotCall field changes
    if(Trigger.IsInsert || 
       oldContact.HasOptedOutOfEmail != newContact.HasOptedOutOfEmail   ||   
       oldContact.DoNotCall != newContact.DoNotCall )
    {    
      ContactUpdates.add(newContact);
    }

if(ContactUpdates.size()>0)
{
    //Find all other contact records with same email address
    for(Contact Con :[SELECT ID, Email, HasOptedOutOfEmail, DoNotCall 
                      FROM Contact where Email =: newContact.Email])
    { 
        //Update those contact records with the same value from the primary one (that triggered this)
        ContactToUpdate.add(
            new Contact(
                Id=Con.id,
                HasOptedOutOfEmail = Con.HasOptedOutOfEmail,
                DoNotCall = Con.DoNotCall
            )
        );
    }

     try
    {
        if(ContactToUpdate.size()>0)
        {
            //fire the update
            update ContactToUpdate;
            system.debug('ContactToUpdate ---' + ContactToUpdate.size());                
        }

    }
        Catch(Exception ee)
        {   
            system.debug('Exception on ContactPrivacySynch ---' +ee.getMessage());
        }


}
} 
}
```

Comment: Clarification - is there a reason you don't want to de-dupe them into a single record?

Comment: Large company, various reason that I can't outline here... we're in the process of a mass dedupe effort, however with GDPR around the corner we'll need this sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINAL CODE w Utility Class to ensure it runs ONCE

```
private void ContactEmailOptPutSynch()

{
List<Contact> ContactUpdates = new List<Contact>();
if(ContactUtility.isFirstRun()){
ContactUtility.setFirstRunFalse();
for( Contact newContact : (List<Contact>)Trigger.new){
    Contact oldContact = NULL;

    //If update, grab old record for comparison
    if(Trigger.IsUpdate) 
    { 
        oldContact = ((Map<Id, Contact>)Trigger.oldMap).get(newContact.ID);  
    }

    //Add to list only if NEW or HasOptedOutOfEmail field changes
    if(Trigger.IsInsert || oldContact.HasOptedOutOfEmail != newContact.HasOptedOutOfEmail )
    {    
      ContactUpdates.add(newContact);
    }

if(ContactUpdates.size()>0)
{
    //Find all other contact records with same email address
    for(Contact Con :[SELECT ID, Email, HasOptedOutOfEmail, DoNotCall, Email_Opt_Out_Flagged__c 
                        FROM Contact where Email =: ContactUpdates[0].Email
                        AND ID !=: newContact.ID 
                        AND LastModifiedDate !=: newContact.LastModifiedDate])
    { 
        system.debug('Con ---' + newContact.ID + ' -- updating --> ' + Con.ID);    
        //Update those contact records with the same value from the primary one (that triggered this)

        if(ContactUpdates[0].HasOptedOutOfEmail == TRUE)
        {
            Con.HasOptedOutOfEmail = ContactUpdates[0].HasOptedOutOfEmail;
            Con.Email_Opt_Out_Flagged__c = system.today();
            update Con;
        }
        if(ContactUpdates[0].HasOptedOutOfEmail == FALSE)
        {
            Con.HasOptedOutOfEmail = ContactUpdates[0].HasOptedOutOfEmail;
            Con.Email_Opt_Out_Flagged__c = NULL;
            update Con;
        }            

    }
}
} 
}
}
```

Contact Utility Class

```
public class ContactUtility {
private static boolean firstRun = true;

public static boolean isFirstRun() {
    return firstRun;
}

public static void setFirstRunFalse(){
    firstRun = false;
}

}
```